# What commands are available via the API?

Tags: iri-node, iri-legacy-api

Where can I find a list of all the commands that the API accepts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SE questions shouldn't duplicate freely available knowledge without an underlying problem. Listing API commands is both trivial and on the other hand hard to keep up-to-date. It's a Google question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API command reference is available here: https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/reference

At the time of answering, the commands are:

- getNodeInfo
- getNeighbors
- addNeighbors
- removeNeighbors
- getTips
- findTransactions
- getTrytes
- getInclusionStates
- getBalances
- getTransactionsToApprove
- attachToTangle
- interruptAttachingToTangle
- broadcastTransactions
- storeTransactions

Comment: Awesome. I found `readme.io` as well, but this is a thrid-party site; should this serve as the source-of-truth moving forward? Or is there also documentation available with source?

Comment: @MattClark that website can be considered official and the most complete source of documentation available on IOTA; it's referenced by the co-founders see for instance https://blog.iota.org/iota-first-chapter-synopsis-506fdf874437

Comment: Either way this should not be duplicated into an SE question.

Comment: @Helmar I do disagree with you here. I was not really looking for an actual list of API commands, the ask was more of, what is the official documentation. I realize SE will not be kept up-to-date, so if the link posted is the official documentation as specified in a blog post.. Then this is a perfectly acceptable question and answer IMO.

Comment: @MattClark that's your prerogative of course. However that's not very obvious from your one sentence question ;)